# How to use Mongo from a JRuby generated Java class?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I am trying to expose the functionality of a ruby gem I wrote to a Java application via JRuby. I'm having a problem getting jruby to load the bson-1.8.5-java gem instead of the native extension bson_ext which doesn't play nice with JRuby. My goal is to make minimal changes to my ruby gem, so I would prefer not to import Java classes in my ruby code.

After compiling my ruby files to Java classes, they are calling `require 'mongo'`

```
public class Goose extends RubyObject  {
    private static final Ruby __ruby__ = Ruby.getGlobalRuntime();
private static final RubyClass __metaclass__;

    static {
        String source = new StringBuilder("require 'mongo'\n" +
            "\n" +
            "class Goose\n" +
            "  def initialize\n" +
        ...
    __ruby__.executeScript(source, "goose.rb");
        ...
```

Calling the class from Java fails complaining about the BSON extension not being loaded.

The problem could be boiled down to

I jar'd up the mongo and bson-java gems according to [this tutorial](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2009/01/10/jruby-1-1-6-gems-in-a-jar/).

```
$ jruby -S gem install -i ./my-gems mongo --no-rdoc --no-ri
Fetching: bson-1.8.5-java.gem (100%)
Fetching: mongo-1.8.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bson-1.8.5-java
Successfully installed mongo-1.8.5
2 gems installed
$ jar cf my-gems.jar -C ./my-gems .
```

And I added my-gems.jar to my Eclipse project classpath.

Then I ran a simple main to test the require evaluation

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("org.jruby.embed.compat.version", "JRuby1.9");
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();

    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("jruby");

    try {
        engine.eval("require 'mongo'");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
      ** Notice: The BSON extension was not loaded. **

  For optimal performance, use of the BSON extension is recommended. To
  enable the extension make sure ENV['BSON_EXT_DISABLED'] is not set.

  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at JavaRubyTest.main(JavaRubyTest.java:27)
  Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) cannot load Java class org.bson.types.ObjectId
...
```

However, if I run `require 'mongo'` from jirb, it loads.

Any pointers?